# Any python library for Bezier curve approximation with biarcs?

Tags: python, bezier, cubic-bezier

I am in need of a simple python library which can perform Bezier curve approximation algorithm with biarcs (biarc interpolation). I am looking for something like the algorithm explained at [approximating-bezier-curves-by-biarcs](http://dlacko.org/blog/2016/10/19/approximating-bezier-curves-by-biarcs/) which also includes CSharp implementation.

I have tried searching, for similar implementation in python. I found some but they were inside in CNC controllers code like gcodetools. Extracting just the part I need, seems to be complicated. And couldn't find any simple ones, which just implement the algorithm.

Before I try to convert CSharp code to python, I want to check here if any such python script already exists. Please share anything you think might be helpful.

Comment: you could roll your own? https://pomax.github.io/bezierinfo/#arcapproximation ([js code](https://github.com/Pomax/bezierjs/blob/master/lib/bezier.js#L844-L948), easy to port to python if you know how to read code)

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans. Just two days ago, I found your Bézier Curves online book and have started reading it.  Very well written !!  Not just the arc approximation, it seems to have all the info needed to work with Bézier Curves.  Many thanks for making this available online. 

I am planning to port your js code to python myself.

Comment: glad to hear it's useful - good luck on the port!